# How to pass checkbox values to a Json Object in ajax/jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Need to create a json object like this:
Course names are checkbox values

Ex:

```
{
  "name" : "abc",
  "branch" : "Computers",
  "courses" : [ {
                   "courseName":"java"
                },

               {
                  "courseName":"C"
               }
        ]
}
```

For this,

I got the values of checkbox like this:

```
   var listOfCourses = [];
    $('#courses:checked').each(function() {

        listOfCourses.push($(this).val());

     });
```

I created student json object:

```
var student = {
        name : $('#name').val(),
        branch : $("#branch").val(),
        courses : courses
    }
```

courses should have the checkbox values as described in the example.

So how do I pass the values in courses?

Ajax function looks like this :

```
$.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost:8080/StudentRegistration/rest/register",
        data : JSON.stringify(student),
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        success : function(data) {
            alert("success" + data);

        },
        error : function(data) {
            alert("error " + data);
        }
    });
```

Please help.

Comment: `$('#courses:checked').each` **each** on an element ID? ID should be unique per- page. Use `.course` for those poor checkboxes.

Comment: Also I see no valid sense in repeating all over again `courseName:` ... `courseName:` use instead: `courses: ["c++", "java", "javascript"]`

Comment: Which is exactly what `courses.push($(this).val())` will do.

Comment: There's no need to send the data as JSON. The normal x-www-form-urlencoded format can handle arrays.